# Unexpected token errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook login help guide to put together a script to check whether a user is logged in. I've put together the following based on [this guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '303594953085775', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://mysite.com/pages/account/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
        login();
    } else {
        // not_logged_in
        login();
    }
    });
    };

  };

  function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
    }

    function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
    }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

I have no idea what I've done wrong as I copied it exactly. I've copied it four times over and it's still getting errors despite it being **exactly** what was written on the Facebook site.

I get two errors:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

I don't really know anything about this kind of complex JavaScript as I only know how to do a few basic calls and stuff, this is currently making me want to throw myself off a building.

Can anyone tell me why it's erroring? **Is there somewhere I can just get hold of the entire correct script and replace my app ID and domain rather than having to go through this silly Facebook guide?**

Comment: do they uncaught SyntaxError messages also have a line and character number with them? as it looks like you have an extra }; after the first fbAsyncInit function

Comment: You are aware you can replace your `if-else` clause with: `if (response.status !== 'connected') login();`

Comment: Is that your real app id? Don't post it in a public forum.

Answer (score 1):

there exist a syntax error in your code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '303594953085775', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'http://mysite.com/pages/account/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Additional init code here
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // connected
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // not_authorized
      login();
  } else {
      // not_logged_in
      login();
  }
  });

};
};        **// REMOVE THIS- This one is extra**
```

You can use Notepad++ or any other good editor to avoid such errors :)

Comment: Thanks, that removes one error but the other remains. The '.' is apparently illegal on line 14. http://pastebin.com/0UMTPdrp - I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . - confused as this was taken direct from Facebook. Their own code is incorrect?!

Comment: @Francesca their code is correct, you can see a modified version in action at philippeharewood.com/facebook/hello.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem which was caused by copy and pasting the code directly, which somehow put some strange characters in there. I fixed it by physically re-writing it, as opposed to direct copy and paste.